# CDI: Setter not working on injected object

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, cdi

I am working on a Java EE RESTful stack using mainly JAX-RS (Jersey) and CDI (Weld), both provided by my Payara (Glassfish) server.

I would like to share contextual information about the flying request between my layers, lets talk only about `loggedUser`, for instance. So I created this class to keep the state:

```
public class RequestContext {

    private User loggedUser;

    public void setLoggedUser(User user) { this.loggedUser = user; }

    public User getLoggedUser() { return this.loggedUser }

}
```

There's also a producer:

```
public class RequestContextProducer {

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    public RequestContext produce() {
        return new RequestContext();
    }

}
```

The requests are intercepted by a JAX-RS RequestFilter:

```
@Provider
@Priority(1)
public class AuthenticationRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Inject
    RequestContext context;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        ...
        context.setLoggedUser(new User());
        ... // context.getLoggedUser() return null here, even just after being setted.
    }
}
```

As you can see commented in the source code, my problem is that the setter method never actually sets anything.

I used to use the same strategy while working with JBOSS and this always worked as expected, so I am puzzled.

I just found out that changing the producer scope to `@Dependent` makes the field get setted, but then, when `RequestContext` is again injected on the below layers, it resolves to a new instance, with null in every fields, including `loggedUser`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you step into context.setLoggedUser(...) and verify that it gets set?

Comment: @efekctive Actually this was the first check I made :/

Comment: You'd be surprised how many people forget this :-} Does it get invoked again? Are you using the same instance of context? Because if it gets set somebody is unsetting it unless between setting and getting context gets switched

Comment: I've done this mistake myself once hehehe, but yea, I think its kinda related to the scope of the instance. Anyways, RequestScoped means alive while the server request is not resolved, or am I missing something?

Comment: @efekctive edited with some extra information

Comment: Does it come from the same producer? Can you put a break point on the producer? Before delving through annotations, it helps to know who is making those calls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134999/discussion-between-marcos-j-c-kichel-and-efekctive).

Comment: The producer is in vain here. Just use [@]Named [@]Requestscoped annotations on RequestContext.

Comment: Yea Ik, but this dont solve my problem